# Save scikit-learn model without datasets

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree, joblib

I've trained a RandomForestClassifier model with the sklearn library and saved it with joblib. Now, I have a joblib file of nearly 1GB which I'm deploying on a Nginx/Flask/Guincorn stack. The issue is I have to find an efficient way to load this model from file and serve API requests. Is it possible to save the model without the datasets when doing:

```
joblib.dump(model, '/kaggle/working/mymodel.joblib')
print("random classifier saved")
```

Comment: Your model seems quite bigger than usual. How many trees are you using? and do you keep the dataset as an attribute of the model?

Comment: Yesterday there was another user asking a very similar question. (S)he was complaining about 20 GB random forest pickle files, and (s)he had tens of them. So, a single 1 GB random forest model does not look bad at all.

Comment: @Chris I'm using 1500 estimators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The persistent representation of Scikit-Learn estimators **DOES NOT** include any training data.

Speaking about decision trees and their ensembles (such as random forests), then the size of the estimator object scales quadratically to the depth of decision trees (ie. the `max_depth` parameter). This is so, because decision tree configuration is represented using `(max_depth, max_depth)` matrices (`float64` data type).

You can make your random forest objects smaller by limiting the `max_depth` parameter. If you're worried about potential loss of predictive performance, you may increase the number of child estimators.

Longer term, you may wish to explore alternative representations for Scikit-Learn models. For example, converting them to PMML data format using the [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance towards max depth